# Adding radio control to c# table

Tags: c#

I am fetching list of record from database and storing it in `DataTable`, then converting it into `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table`

After that adding a Radio button control `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton` to each of `Table` row.

but i am getting error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on line `tOutput.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));`

Code :

```
string sReturn = "";
Table tOutput;
HtmlInputRadioButton rdoProperty;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
try
{
    DataTable dtOutput = new DataTable();
    dtOutput = IstaDAL.getPropertyList(sProjectID);

    if (dtOutput.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        tOutput = convertDataTable2HTMLTable(dtOutput, true, true, false);

        foreach(TableRow trOutput in tOutput.Rows)
        {
            if (trOutput.TableSection == TableRowSection.TableBody)
            {
                rdoProperty = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                rdoProperty.Attributes["value"] = trOutput.Cells[1].Text;
                rdoProperty.Attributes["name"] = "rdoProperty";
                trOutput.Cells[0].Controls.Add(rdoProperty);
            }
        }

        tOutput.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
        sReturn = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**When i did some research by trying to get inside `rdoProperty` i found one of his property `get_RenderedNameAttribute` is causing that exception**

Stacktrace :

```
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton.get_RenderedNameAttribute()
```

Comment: @GrantWinney : No it doesnt. Actually it return `HtmlTable` , As i can see values in `trOutput.Cells[1].Text;` for every iteration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do anyone have better solution that this ?

Instead of using this

```
trOutput.Cells[0].Controls.Add(rdoProperty);
```

I now came up with this

```
trOutput.Cells[0].Text = "<input type='radio' name='some name'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(tOutput!=null)
{    
using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
        tOutput.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    }
}
    sReturn=sw.ToString();
```

Comment: Not working. it is going inside `if` loop but same error. check question edit for stacktrace

Comment: Try giving unique name inside each iteration.rdoProperty.Attributes["name"] = "rdoProperty_"+counter;

Comment: i guess `name` has to be same for radio button control ?